# How to setup simplest audio live broadcast with WOWZA server?

Tags: audio, broadcast, wowza

I want to broadcast an event's audio on my website, I have a wowza server in data center.

Can anyone suggest what is the simplest (cheapest) setup in the venue and wowza so that I can broadcast the audio live on my website with the use of wowza server in data center?

Comment: Hi, is the wowza server yours or you use a cloud service?

Comment: Hi Jabal, it is my server, not using cloud service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a high-level overview of the steps you need to make. Sorry, but I can't really give a more specific answer to such a general question. Hope it helps:

- Install Flash Media Live Encoder on a PC and plug in the audio
- Set up the encoding to contain only the audio, set the "FMS URL" to your Wowza server address and use the default "live" application that comes with that
- Start your Wowza server and you should see FMLE connecting
- Embed a JW Player on your website and source it from Wowza. (If you stream audio-only, JW Player will show a black box, which you can work around by adding a nice spash image)

Comment: Thanks Jabal, you have solved my problem, I have now able to stream my audio with your method (and some google searching).  Many thanks